# What does splitting a variable mean in a postive/negative part?

Tags: linear-programming

I am currently studying linear programming and came across a specific problem that involves substitution and variable conversion. Although I have consulted relevant resources, I am still a bit confused about a few aspects. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help clarify the following questions:

The Use of Substitution:
In a linear programming problem I encountered, the author suggests applying the substitution $x_1 = x_1^+ - x_1^-$ and performing conversions as explained on page 6 of the "Linear programming problems" slides. I'm curious about the purpose and benefits of this substitution. Why is it necessary or advantageous to use such a substitution in this context?

Application Limited to $x_1$:
Another aspect that puzzles me is that the substitution $x_1 = x_1^+ - x_1^-$ is only applied to $x_1$, while leaving $x_2$ unchanged. I would like to understand why the substitution is limited to $x_1$ and not extended to $x_2$ as well. Are there specific reasons or mathematical considerations behind this choice?

**Problem**

$\begin{array}{ll}\min & 3 x_1-2 x_2 \\ \text { s.t. } & 2 x_1+5 x_2 \geq 10 \\ & 4 x_1+2 x_2=8 \\ & -2 \leq x_1 \leq 7 \\ & 3 \leq x_2 \leq 10\end{array}$

**Solution**

I don't manage to convert this to clear LaTex, therefore a screenshot
[image]

Here , $x_1$ is substituted with $x_{1}^{+}$ & $x_{1}^{-}$ , though $x_2$ is not substituted. Why ?

Comment: It is the last line which gives the Clue **[[ The Answer is Non-Negativity ]]** $x_{1}^{+}$ & $x_{1}^{-}$ & $x_{2}$ should not be Negative. We can not make that claim about $x_{1}$ which has Positive & 0 & Negative Possibilities. With that Substitution , we can make that Claim !

Comment: @prem Thank you, I think I understand it better now

Comment: It will be great to include (1) the Author (2) the web-link to the Slides : The Post will be more Complete with that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating my Earlier Comment :

In general , we use Non-Negative variables in linear Programming.

(1) When given variable $A$ is Directly Non-Negative , we have the Non-Negativity Constraint $A \ge 0$.

(2) When given variable $B$ is Directly Non-Positive , we have the Constraint $B \le 0$ , where we introduce new variable $B^{-}=-B$ & we add the Non-Negativity Constraint $B^{-} \ge 0$.

(3) When given variable $C$ is having Positive & Negative range , we have the Constraint $-X \le C \le +Y$ where we introduce new variables $C^{+},C^{-}$ where we make $C=C^{+}-C^{-}$. We then add the Constraints $C^{+}-C^{-} \ge -X$ & $C^{+}-C^{-} \le +Y$. We can then add the Non-Negativity Constraints $C^{-} \ge 0$ & $C^{+} \ge 0$.

These Substitutions will all result in variables which are Non-Negative.
The Original variables & the Solutions may or may not be Non-Negative.